# SQLite: How do I search multiple values?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two autocomplettextview and 3 columns in my table col1,col2,col3. col1 is primary key

table look like this:

```
| col1 | col2   |  col3                 |
-----------------------------------------
| 1    | store1 |apple,pineapple,mango  |
| 2    | store2 | apple,orange          |
| 3    | store3 | apple,pineapple,orange|
| 4    | store4 | orange,mango          |
| 5    | store5 | mango,jackfruit       |
```

I have two questions:

**Q1**: can i store multiple values in single column.If No then how can I store?

**Q2**: previously said i have two autocompletetextview to search

I.e.:

If user types apple and pineapple in *two autocompletetextview* then I need to 
display row that matches these two texts.

**Expected o/p**:

```
| col1 | col2   |  col3                 |
-----------------------------------------
| 1    | store1 |apple,pineapple,mango  |
| 2    | store3 | apple,pineapple,orange|
```

how can I achieve this?

I gone through several reseaches, with the help of `foreign key` I can store multiple values in single column, but how can I use *foreign key* in `Where clause` to achieve `expected o/p`.

Comment: please learn some sql basics ... you can join tables + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: for your first question yous should create two table and simply join them !

Comment: If you have 2 questions, then pls ask them in separate posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldnt store multiple values in same column. Instead you should use three tables.

Then is easy to find what StoreID have both food

```
SELECT FoodAvailable.StoreID
FROM FoodAvailable
JOIN Foods
  ON FoodAvailable.FoodID = Foods.FoodID
WHERE Foods.Food in ('apple', 'pineapple')
GROUP BY FoodAvailable.StoreID
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

**Store**

```
| StoreID | StoreName |
-----------------------
| 1       | store1    |
| 2       | store2    |
| 3       | store3    |
| 4       | store4    |
| 5       | store5    |
```

**Food**

```
| FoodID  | Food      | 
-----------------------
| 1       | apple     |
| 2       | pineapple |
| 3       | mango     |
| 4       | orange    |
| 5       | jackfruit |
```

**FoodAvailable**

```
| StoreID | FoodID | 
---------------------
| 1       | 1      | //apple 
| 1       | 2      | //pineapple
| 1       | 3      | //mango  
| 2       | 1      | //apple 
| 2       | 4      | //orange
| 3       | 1      | //apple 
| 3       | 2      | //pineapple
| 3       | 4      | //orange
| 4       | 4      | //orange
| 4       | 3      | //mango  
| 5       | 3      | //mango  
| 5       | 5      | //jackfruit
```

Your Final query is something like this

```
SELECT f.StoreID, GROUP_CONCAT(food ORDER BY food DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM FoodAvailable f
WHERE f.StoreID = (SELECT FoodAvailable.StoreID
                   FROM FoodAvailable
                   JOIN Foods
                     ON FoodAvailable.FoodID = Foods.FoodID
                   WHERE Foods.Food in ('apple', 'pineapple')
                   GROUP BY FoodAvailable.StoreID
                   HAVING count(*) = 2
                  )
GROUP BY f.StoreID
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reponse..I need to display according to user's search then how we can use IN operator @Juan

Comment: User can search anything in autocompletextview then how can I enter apple,pineapple in IN operator.user can also type orange,apple or some other combinations @Juan

Comment: *Instead you should use two tables* ... 3 tables(Store, Food, FoodInStore) ... there is no sens in repeating fruits multiple times